# Query to select all events of table that correspond to selected month

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a dateTimePicker and a I want a DGV to populate with a query that select from DB (SQL CE) all entries that correspond to the selected month on the dateTimePicker.

This would be the logic

```
SELECT FROM Employees WHERE (@MonthEnd or @MonthEnd2) = dateTimePicker1.SelectedMonth
```

The values from @MonthEnd or @MonthEnd2 are datetime.

How I would first select the current month on the dateTimePicker?

After I should convert datetime from DB to string? Or int? Then how should I select only the month part of the data to compare with selected month of the calendar?

EDIT: Thanks to @Hogan I was able to come up with this code: (hope it be helpful to people in need like I was (I asked for a datetimepicker, but used a calendar instead)).

```
string constringF = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
            string QueryF = "select * from Funcionarios  where datepart(month, datafimcontrato) = @mes ";
            SqlCeConnection conDataBaseF = new SqlCeConnection(constringF);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBaseF = new SqlCeCommand(QueryF, conDataBaseF);
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@mes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month);
```

Comment: you do realize that this SQL will select any entry with that month, totally ignoring the year right? So if you pick August in your date picker, you'll get records from August 2015, 2014, 2013...

Comment: Yes I do, but that fullfills my needs, in time I can come with similar approuch if I need current calendar years or even days.

Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called month.  You can use it like this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Emp
 WHERE MONTH(datefieldintable) = @MonthInput
```

Comment: It worked like a charm!

Thanks a lot for your helpful answer.

I will update the question with the actually code I came up, because I'm currently using SQL CE and the query is slightely different.

Thanks a lot once more!